# Do I have to release accessoryView?

Tags: iphone

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView adTarget:selfaction:@selector(switchChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[switchView release];
```

I allocated switch view in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:.
Do I have to release cell.accessoryView in dealloc?

Isn't this better than above?

```
cell.accessoryView = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can release your switch as soon as you set `cell.accessoryView`. There isn't much difference between the 2 snippets, except it is generally recommended that you should release the memory explicitly wherever you can. `Autorelease` is generally used otherwise, such as when you have to return a value from a method.

Comment: So, do I have to release in dealloc like this [cell.accessoryView release] or not?

Comment: No. It will release itself when the cell is released.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of this question, they both do the same thing. There's really no difference between them.

Calling `autorelease` can be thought of as doing the same thing as calling `release` in terms of memory management rules - it's actually a deferred release call. You're basically saying, "please release this object at some point in the future". Of course, in your example calling `[switchView release]` will only decrement the retain count, not completely release the object, since you've retained it by setting it to be the cell's accessory view.

There is a similar example that deals with the pros/cons (or lack thereof) here:

[Autorelease vs. Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776494/autorelease-vs-release)

You can read Apple's guidelines and documentation on autorelease pools here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI